# Export gridview data to a excel sheet is giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have a asp.net application where in i am displaying a grid view whose code is shown below

```
 <center><asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
         GridLines="None">
 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333"></RowStyle>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    </asp:GridView>
 </center>
 <center> <table>
 <tr>
 <td>
    <asp:Button ID="btnWordConvert" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        onclick="btnWordConvert_Click" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
```

in cs

```
 protected void btnWordConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Customers.doc"));
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();

}
```

i am getting error on `GridView1.RenderControl(htw);` line and the error is `Control 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.` Any help are appreciated.

Comment: the error tells itself the solution. Place your `gridview` inside the `form` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this is, a  server control is rendered outside of a **form** tag by calling [GridView.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rendercontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fbid=FpD83w-fL5Y).

You could avoid this by overriding [VerifyRenderingInServerForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Have a look at [this](http://aspalliance.com/771_CodeSnip_Exporting_GridView_to_Excel).

Comment: Its downloading.But when i open the downloaded document a `File Coversion` window is been opening in Microsoft word.The document shows only `<div> </div>`

Comment: It is because you are saving your response to an ms-word content type. If you want to save it as excel, you should change it to the correct content type.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code inside form tag.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

   //put your code here
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your gridview is inside **form** tag.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
         GridLines="None">
                        ... ... ... 
    </asp:GridView>
 </form>
```

Comment: i tried that thing and its giving error as `page can use only one server side tag`

Comment: are u using master page approach

Answer (score 0):

put following method

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
      /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}
```